# production server fails to upload wide images

Tags: php, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload, blueimp, wideimage

This is the situation:

I'm building a symfony2 web site, and I'm using the (excellent) vx/js-upload-bundle bundle in order to integrate blueimp's jQuery-File-Upload component.

On my computer (of course) I had no problems, but on the production server some images wouldn't upload.
After many tests we found that the only common thing was their dimensions. They were all big images, dimension wise... (we successfully uploaded files with bigger filesize ).

We tried setting limits on the images (max_width, max_height) but that didn't help.
Tried hacking the uploader code - also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally (after ~3 days of playing with it), we found the cause!
php.ini's "memory_limit" was set to 32M by the hosting company (the default is 128M).

The upload code does some image manipulation (it can create thumbnails and lots of other cool things), that requires more memory... I changed it to 128M and everything works.

This is the thread that gave me the clue:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1113

(Thanks for that :-)  )